# NHibernate "Could not find a part of the path" problem

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to use NHibernate with my project, I've generated NHibernate class and xml file using NGen. After that, I try to test my application but when I run to second line of this code.

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.Configure();
```

It show error message like below.

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\App\bin\Debug\hbm\MyFile.hbm.xml'.

Obviously this file doesn't exist, because it's located in D:\App\bin\Debug**\Data**\hbm\MyFile.hbm.xml

I want to know how to solving this problem?

Comment: Try learning Fluent NHibernate, and say goodbye to all those annoying hbm.xml files... :)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to set your file (MyFile.hbm.xml) as "**Embedded Resource**" in your Visual Studio project (**Properties** on File -> **Build Action** : **Embedded Resource**), and then, recompile, it'll be fine.

Comment: I already done that but these files are located in another project, so after compile they ware located in "sub-folder\hbm" not \hbm